# Cannot assign to the result of this expression when setting table view's dataSource

Tags: cocoa, swift

I want to use `NSTableView` in my Cocoa app and hence I have to set the table view's `NSTableViewDataSource` delegate to `self`. However, the following code doesn't compile due to the error `Cannot assign to the result of this expression`.

```
myTable.dataSource = self
```

And I did declare the `myTable` variable as like this:

```
@IBOutlet var myTable: NSTableView
```

Also note that I correctly declare my AppDelegate conforms to `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol.

So what's wrong with the above two lines?

Also, is it correct that I declare the table view as `@IBOutlet var myTable: NSTableView`? Or should I define it as optional or implicitly unwrapped optional variable?

Comment: Err why the downvotes ???

Comment: where are you assigning `myTable.dataSource = self`? You cannot access `self` in a few locations where `self` has not been initialized yet

Comment: Also your current declaration is correct, `@IBOutlet` implicitly makes your variable an `implicitly unwrapped optional`

Comment: I assigned it within `awakeFromNib()`, which is what a book I'm reading right now did (though it uses Objective-C and Xcode 4, not Swift and Xcode 6 beta)...

Comment: BTW, when I moved the code outside of the `awakeFromNib()`, then the error message changed to `Expected declaration` and the code still cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though `NSTableView` has not been fully modernized. Its `dataSource` property is still informal, existing as just accessor methods, rather than being a declared property using `@property`. Therefore, the Swift interface doesn't have a `dataSource` property. It has the methods `dataSource()` and `setDataSource()`.

So, try:

```
myTable.setDataSource(self)
```

Comment: Awesome! That resolved the issue and now the build succeeds. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you should file a bug with Apple so that this has a chance of being fixed in the near term.

Answer (score 0):

IBOutlet properties are automatically made weak implicitly unwrapped optionals that are initially set to nil.

You can directly access the value safely using an if let:

```
if let table = myTable{
    table.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: I tried that before posting this question, but it still returned the same error message...

Comment: `Cannot assign to 'dataSource' in 'table'` when I wrote `table.dataSource = self`, while `Cannot assign to the result of this expression` when I wrote `myTable.dataSource = self`, both within the body of `if` statement.

Comment: does your self implement the datasource protocol?

Comment: I did declare it as `class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSPopoverDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource { ... }`